# Add Trailing Slash to URLs

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

There are quite a few results for [add trailing slash .htaccess](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=add+trailing+slash+.htaccess) on Google, but all examples I found require the use of your domain name, as in this example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

My problem is that a hard-coded domain name will not work on my local development machine. Is there a way to add trailing slashes without explicitly telling  mod_rewrite the domain name?

Comment: Looks like a question that belongs more on serverfault.com instead of stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 7):

You don’t need to specify the domain, you can simply use an absolute URL path:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

That does also make a check for the URL scheme obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: .* will match backslashes, use [^/]* instead

Comment: err, in addition to I meant, such as Gumbo uses below.

Comment: @Oz, yes that would be better. I was merely demonstrating the use of %{HTTP_HOST}, so I went for minimal change of the originally given snippet.