# Add Trailing Slash .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, slash, trailing-slash

I'm trying to get the following effect (using this local file `http://localhost/[company_name]/[project_name]/.htaccess`):

```
http://localhost/[company_name]/[project_name]/page-1 (adds slash)
http://localhost/[company_name]/[project_name]/page-1/ (does nothing)
http://localhost/[company_name]/[project_name]/page-1/subpage-1 (adds slash)
http://www.example.com/page-1 (adds slash)<br />
http://www.example.com/page-1/ (does nothing)
etc.
```

The thing I want to accomplish is that this .htaccess doesn't need the path `http://localhost/[company_name]/[project_name]/` anymore so that I don't have to edit this each time it's been uploaded.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

I found the code above here: [Add Trailing Slash to URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668096/add-trailing-slash-to-urls), but it only makes it possible to use the HOST dynamically and discards the path. Does someone a solution to accomplish this effect?

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

This code needs to be put at the top of your .htaccess file below RewriteEngine On

Comment: Don't think this works to turn

www.mydomain.com

into

www.mydomain.com/

Comment: The root domain is not included.

on the webserver the http://www.mydomain.com and http://www.mydomain.com/ have exactly the same URI.

For SEO reasons, they are treated as the same for the root domain, with or without trailing slashes

Comment: add ^$  in condition to avoid '/' at the end of domain

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.|^$) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

Comment: This code needs to be put  at the top of your .htaccess file below RewriteEngine On

Comment: Please mention in answer that it will  work when you put these lines on top of .htaccess file.

Comment: Is this working in 2021? I tested on firefox and it's not working. I have a www.test.com/product and it should be displayed like www.test.com/product/ but it's not working

Comment: @user9437856 This worked fine for me now. WP site acting up randomly not redirecting to trailing slash.

Comment: How can we exclude GET requests?

Comment: This should be ``RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) `` to ``RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\/$|\.)`` . One trailing was missing.

Answer (score 2):

Please add below lines top of .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
#Add Trailing slash for end of the URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use this format in `.htaccess,`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with all other answers: POST requests lose their data when redirected.
You can instruct the browser to resend the POST data by using http 307:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=307]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307

Btw I prefer the REQUEST_FILENAME condition. This makes sure that the request really targets a folder structure and not appends the slash to file Urls.