# laravel 4.1 force redirect/show 404 if without trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4

I have old website and converted it to laravel 4.1; removed cut off trailing slash from htaccess.

The problem is that you can view the page without trailing slash and it is bad as can be abused in future

So I need to either to redirect 301 to page with trailing slash or show 404
how can I do this in elegant way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found here the htaccess method if sm1 interested [Add Trailing Slash .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829714/add-trailing-slash-htaccess)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)

RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you want. It will redirect everything without a trailing slash to the page with a trailing slash.

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: i found htaccess solution
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] and it worked