# .htaccess redirect to url with trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Please help me with redirect in .htaccess 
 I need redirect to url with trailing slash

www.example.cz/about--> www.example.cz/about/ 
www.example.cz/index.php?path=about --> www.example.cz/about/

and last 
www.example.cz/index.php --> www.example.cz

```
#MY .htaccess
<FilesMatch "\.phtml$">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny From All
</FilesMatch>

ErrorDocument 404 /404/

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.cz$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.cz/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Have you already tried something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add Trailing Slash .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829714/add-trailing-slash-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

I solved trailing slash and index.php duplicates :)

```
<FilesMatch "\.phtml$">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny From All
</FilesMatch>

ErrorDocument 404 /404/

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.cz$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.cz/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://example.cz/$1 [R=301,L]    

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /?path=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Now .htaccess doing

```
www.example.cz/index.php --> www.example.cz/
www.example.cz/about--> www.example.cz/about/
example.cz --> www.example.cz
```

Next, I need to solve

```
www.example.cz/?path=about--> www.example.cz/about/
www.example.cz/about/ --> wwww.example.cz
```