# Htaccess adding slash on end of url

Tags: .htaccess

I have to made some changes in my htaccess if it is possible,

There is my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9.\/\-\?\&]+)/.php$ blog.php?id=$1
```

It is rewrite for get method wich one hide ?id= and it's work perfectly, so i have problem if i take of from url slash (/) then i get 404 erorr.
I need to made RewriteRull which one make slash on end of url if is url without slash.

So if is possible to make some if statement which one detect url without slash and add it. Or make RewriteRull for that url?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to your .htaccess file may just what you want:

```
DirectorySlash On
```

Comment: Thanks, i try that solution but it is not work.
It's work on directory but it this case not

Comment: Perhaps have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829714/add-trailing-slash-htaccess