# Trailing slash redirect based on url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have single htaccess file for many domains and I need to force a trailing slash at the end of my url for a specific domain only.

I have tried the existing rewrite conditions and they work globally I just need a domain specific solution.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: *"force a trailing slash at the end of my url for a specific domain only"* ... then you'll need to target that specific domain in the RewriteCond

Answer (score 1):

you can do this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC] !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

seems duplicate question : [Add Trailing Slash .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829714/add-trailing-slash-htaccess)

Comment: If it's a duplicate it should be closed as such ... but in this case I think the specific domain requirement (e.g. you need to do a RewriteCond match on `%{HTTP_HOST}`) means it's not *quite* a duplicate of the answer you're linking to ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Request_URI with actual domain

Maybe like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %www.example.com /+[^.]+$ 
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```