# How to add slash at the end of the URL?

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following rules given in my .htaccess file everything works perfectly with only one exception:

```
#Active mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on

#Name of APP
RewriteBase /web

#DirectorySlash Off

Options -MultiViews

#Remove web/ from URLs using a redirect rule
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+/)?web/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2? [R=301,L,NE]

#Disable WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
#Active HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} assets/(css|fonts|js|img)/(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ assets/%1/%2 [L,R]

#Add slash at the end (/)
#RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ product.php?id=$1
```

The error of that exception, is when I try to enable in the URL always the slash / end, by:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

And, doing so, rules on file exclusions are lost

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} assets/(css|fonts|js|img)/(.+)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ assets/%1/%2 [L,R]
```

And, even worse, when I try to access a product, it shows this in the URL

```
https://example.org/product.php/?id=mi-producto-de-url-amigable/?
```

All a mess, I have reviewed some articles, also by this means, I have tried the alternatives suggested in each post as `RewriteRule ^(.*[^/]$) $1/ [R,QSA,L]` and, among others but without success .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Add Trailing Slash .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829714/add-trailing-slash-htaccess)

Have you tried this yet?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It seems to work, I'm testing from the cell phone and, as noted, it works fine ;)

Comment: So now my question will be a duplicate :( or I can accept your answer.