# .htaccess rewrite rule for adding a trailing slash by unmatching a string in the URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

The following .htaccess rule un-matches string admin and adds a trailing slash(/) to that URL if admin is not found in the URL

```
RewriteRule ^((?!admin).)*((?!\/).)$ /$1/ [L,R]
```

But it has an error, and it is

```
  http://www.domain.com/index
```

should result to :
      http://www.domain.com/index/

But currently it is resulting:
      http://www.domain.com/inde/

Please find a solution to correct it.
Thanks Very much .

Comment: Did you build the regexp yourself?

Comment: A similar question is here: [Add Trailing to URls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668096/add-trailing-slash-to-urls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression captured the last character in a group.

This will solve the issue:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!.*admin)(.*?)\/?$ /$1/ [L,R]
```

Check out the explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/kL6pV1

Note: this will invalidate any URL that *contains* `admin`, not necessarily starting with `admin`