# Add Trailing Slash to URLs - Development and Production Same Rules

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, trailing-slash

I've spent a bit of time attempting different methods for adding trailing slashes to my URLs, such as this one:

[Add Trailing Slash to URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668096/add-trailing-slash-to-urls)

On my production site, this is working fine with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1$2/ [R=301,L]
```

But it's not working on my local development setup. I run the local sites at `localhost:9090`, so when I go to an URL such as `localhost:9090/users/new/` I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

I've tried a similar rule using `%{HTTP_POST}` and this doesn't work either. I feel like I'm missing something and searching the web keeps pointing me to rules I've already tried.

What is the best way to have a rule that works for both development and production?

**NOTE**

After some great advice from @anubhava, I reorganized my rules and found some better rules for existing needs. I ended up going with a new PHP extension rule and his recommendation and it's working now on both `localhost` and production.

Comment: Are you sure you have mod_rewrite turned on? What's your error logs say?

Comment: I do have mod_rewrite on, as there are several other rules in play, eg removing PHP extension, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `$2` in your regex.

Can you try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?[^/])$ /$1/ [R=302,L]

# hiding .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Try it out in a new browser to avoid 301 caching issues.

Comment: I've tried `/$1/` and `/$1$2/` in an attempt to cover multiple levels of directories. Both don't work on new browser. Should `/$1/` cover URLs like `example.com/test/dir/path/`?

Comment: Run this in Firebug and see what you get in NEt tab

Comment: Run in Chrome, under Firebug > Network: GET method, 500 internal server error, type: text/html

Comment: Yes, I've tried my original with only `/$1/` and your exact rule. Both are giving 500 on new browsers with no cached 301s. In reviewing logs, there might be something valuable in there...  Looking now.

Comment: Do you have more rules in .htaccess? OR any other .htaccess?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40401/discussion-between-nicorellius-and-anubhava)